# what is best way to save css directly from browser inspection?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am looking a best solution to save css when I change it in browser, and finding a tool  or extension with very little configurationto do it in **chrome**. anyone can help please?

Comment: Canyou just edit it with notepad+ and press F5 on the browser to reload the page?

Comment: @EdHeal People can waste their tym playing Farmville on FB but they don't have tym to press f5 when they are developing

Comment: you are right but what is wrong with learning something new?

Comment: @virgoniz Never rely on such things, yes it is always right to learn new things but assume that you started enjoying working like this, one day you debugged and edited entire stylesheet in the browser and suddenly browser crashed..

Comment: @Mr.Alien that is true, So I am never gonna work like that on a project, and by the way I got what I looked for, bellow. thanx for suggestion.

Comment: @virgoniz yes, I said that for maintaining some good practice, you don't know when your things get messed up, better waste 5 mins more instead of making the whole thing again

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/) about this [plugin](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave) which allows automatic saving of your modifications to sources in dev-tools.

**NB**: The addition to the built-in functionalities of Chrome are the **automatic** saving as you can save the sources manually in Chrome without any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is built into Chrome – you don't need an extension.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg&t=8m20s has the details, as attaching loads of screenshots probably isn't the best thing here.